# EmguCV - accentuation in text draw

Tags: c#, opencv, draw, emgucv

I need to accentuate a word using Image  .Draw, however I am not getting. My code follows:

```
MCvFont f = new MCvFont(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1.2, 1.2);
img.Draw("Tietê - Barra Bonita", ref f, new Point(12, 25), new Bgr(0, 0, 0));
```

The problem is in the word TIETÊ which is being viewed as TIET?

I am grateful for the help,

A Hug,

Richard J. Algarve